# Global variable in iOS TabBar Application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, global-variables

I am creating ios app in xcode 4.2.
I have outside file with database. I dont wanna download data in every view. How should i create one global variable for tabbar application? And when should i upload this database before closing of application?

Comment: You should create and use singleton instance. For second question i cannot give you good answer.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use singletones like this: in class DataBase with some arrays of data i implement share method:

```
+(id)share
{
    static id share = nil;

    if (share == nil) {
        share = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return share;
}
```

and then in some classes: self.dataBase = [DataBase share];

Answer (score 5):

In iOS applications the model data is often kept in a *singleton*, rather than in a global variable. [Here is an article briefly describing singletons in Objective-C.](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)

You can load your data in the class method that initializes your shared singleton. Uploading the data back is a bit trickier, because the singleton itself does not know when to do it. Therefore you should make an instance method `-(void)uploadData` in your singleton class, and call that method when your application is about to close. `applicationWillResignActive:` method of your application delegate is a good place to initiate the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variables by doing this

```
extern NSString *someString;

@interface ......

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;

@end

@implementation ......

@systhesize someString;

NSString *someString;

@end
```